# Custom Map rendering in React/TS/JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, json, typescript

I am trying to load a custom map(ie the data is provided by the user) and wanted to know the means that i can possible render this data onto the screen in a container. The map that is being loaded will have a live data feed being overlayed onto it and be interact-able to some extent. The data being shared by the user will be in GeoJSON or .shp format.

How can I virtualise the entire global coordinate system? I am not concerned regarding an "out of box" approach. I believe I can utilise a svg file and then render the geojson data over it but how do i convert/coorelate each geographical coordinate on the svg?

All my google/stackoverflow search regarding loading and rendering GeoJSON files lead me to utilise a prebuilt map library which would be of no use to me. To give an insight as to how the map could look here is an image.
[Sample map being rendered](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UPq1X.png)
To add more details regarding the image - it renders an object file that contains GeoJson data. I am not willing to utilise a third party map.

Comment: Can you provide some additional details (or even some code) on the technology used to render the map? Also, some details on the live data feed would be of great help (format, mode of communication, e.g. event sourcing, websockets, etc.)

Comment: Sounds like you have not built anything yet? I dont think there is a package out there that could out of the box provided you with the map from the image. I would recommend looking into `leaflet` and since you mention react  use the react wrapper `react-leaflet` https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/react-leaflet

Comment: @Disco the problem with react leaflet is that it will bind me to use an "openstreet" map. As i said i don't really want to do that. Is there any way where i can virtualise the entire coordinate system? My concern is not regarding the "out of box" approach. To add more details regarding the image - it renders an object file that contains GeoJson data. I do not want a third party map. I want to be able to convert the coordinate system into a renderable format on the screen.

Comment: @KostasMinaidis for the first part refer to the above comment. For the live data feed - it will mostly be an api call and the data would be in JSON format. Am not too worried about the live data right now. I am more focused onto rendering a geoJSON map.

Comment: If you provide more details about the technology that is going to render the map, we can probably provide some suggestions like React Portals or useRef for accessing HTML elements and rendering something onto them.

Comment: @KostasMinaidis I don't think i can understand what you are trying to ask but at this point I am just using react. The geojson data will be loaded in a div element. As far as "what is a geojson data?" go i suggest you check [this out](https://geojson.org/)

Comment: You do not have to use openstreet with leaflet. It is just a map package that you can show tile maps, most common is to use OMS since its free. You can have other layer such as geoJson, custom polygon layers and so on. https://leafletjs.com/examples/choropleth/